# How to exclude a particular jar from jdk/jre in favour of my own source code (jar)?

Tags: java, maven, java-11

My dev java version is jdk-11. My dev IDE is eclipse and build tool is maven.
I want to exclude a particular jar/pacakge from jdk in favour of my own source code with some additional logging and functionality as well. (I know this might not be advisable to modify jdk source code and use part of it in the project directly. But I can ignore this for a while.)

Take for example, i want to add a modified source version of package `javax.naming`.
So i have extracted the src.zip from jdk installation directory. And added the source code under `javax.naming` package directly in my project.
**Now the compiler warns me**

> The package javax.naming.directory conflicts with a package accessible
> from another module: java.naming

1. Is there a way i can fix the above error.
2. Or exclude the jar/package `java.naming` from jdk while keeping the rest of jars from jdk/jre
3. or Any other approach i can take. I am not looking at inheritance or extension. My modified code is going to be throw away code eventually.

Comment: You can create different classloader and load your application new new classloader with this package.

Comment: @GauravJeswani, but currently i am still facing compiler error. To get to your solution, my code should compile in first place.

Comment: This warning is during compilation from cmd or compilation in some IDE like eclipse? Mostly I have seen such warning in IDEs but not when using cmd to build.

Comment: @GauravJeswani, at the end i still want to debug the code in eclipse. So fixing it in IDE is crucial for me.

Comment: I would think you could have the jar in a separate package and import that.

Comment: @DavidTejuosho - might be that will work, but then i will have to change the other source code (imports) that earlier depended on the original jdk jar. And also I should change the package name for each of the class I am going to touch.

Comment: Looking if there is a easily usable approach.

Comment: JDK 11 is organized in *modules*, so there is no jar to exclude. You can easily exclude a module by not using it, but only if you’re using the module system. A non-modular software placed on the classpath will always see all JDK modules.